# My wordpress shortcode is not working and outputs "unknown"

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create shortcode from the things I have used in my template, but for some reason it returns unknown as src output.
Here is the shortcode I am trying to use:

```
function video( $atts, $content = null ) {

    $link1      = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'vid' , true );
    $search     = '#(.*?)(?:href="https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*#x';
    $replace    = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2';
    $link2        = preg_replace($search,$replace,$link1);
    $link3        = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="'.$link2.'" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $link4        = preg_match('~iframe.*src="([^"]*)"~', $link3, $result);
    $link5        = $result[1];         
    $output .= '<div id="videox" style="z-index:102">';
    $output .= '<div class="video" style="margin-top: 0px; z-index:102; margin-bottom: 0px;">';
    $output .= '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="';
    $output .= $link5;
    $output .= '" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output;
        }

add_shortcode( 'video', 'video' );
```

Result:"src output is empty"

Update:

```
$link1      = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'vid' , true );
```

can be

```
$link1      = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoid" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

or

```
$link1      = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid';
```

Because of this, I had to make iframe again.

Comment: Where did you define `$output`?

Comment: If you know the src of the iframe (`$link2`), why are you making an iframe/html, and parsing it with regex to get the same value? eeek

Comment: @LawrenceCherone because, if meta_key vid is filled with only url and not an embed code, i have to put it again into iframe to be able to do preg_match, otherwise src="unknown"

Comment: I would advice you to rewrite your question. The obvious problem is with your regular expression, and hand litle to do with Wordpress.
try an online regex cheker: https://regex101.com/

Comment: "Because of this, I had to make iframe again." > Does it matter? WordPress parses YT links in content blocks. Just echo it an let WP do the rest, I would say.

Comment: And I only post youtube links?

Comment: Did you try it once?

Comment: Yeah, I have problem with $link5 or $result[1], if I echo it directly into template <?php echo $link5; ?> instead of shortcode it works, but I do not know how to turn this into working shortcode, as it obviously wants to be echoed.

Comment: In your shortcode callback function, parse your link using the `the_content` filter: `apply_filters( 'the_content', $link )`

Comment: Tried, and the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```
$url1       = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'video_play', true);
```